# How do I go about taking screenshots of every dynamically loaded page using Express and Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm creating an app where I want to generate pictures of QR codes along with some other text content, which will be generated dynamically [using qrcode library]. That QR code will be rendered to an endpoint with the help of PugJS templating & ExpressJS. I have to store save the picture of this rendered screen, which I'm doing using Puppeteer. This works just fine when generating *one* QR code and taking a snapshot, or taking multiple snapshots of a single QR code. What I'm looking for is to generate a QR code, take its snapshot, then generate the next QR code, take its snapshot, and so on.

The problem I'm facing in this is that since Puppeteer driver function is asynchronous in nature, the only way I think I can take multiple screenshots is if I put it inside a for loop and then execute it like given in the code below. But this doesn't work for larger values of i (=100) since we are essentially creating a headless chrome every time i iterates, and gives the following error:

```
   (node:34536) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to limit
   (node:34536) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I tried putting the for loop after the 'get' express method and before render to reduce memory load, I've tried changing execution flow in the asynchronous code.

```
   const express = require('express');
   const JsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');
   const { Canvas } = require("canvas");
   const app = express();
   const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
   const QRCode = require('qrcode')
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
   app.set('view engine', 'pug');
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var renderdeet;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){QRCode.toDataURL(process.env.QR_CODE_URL+'sku_type'+process.env.QR_CODE_SUFFIX+'item', function(err, url) {
        renderdeet = { item: 'ANYTHING'+i, packingDate:'17-10-2019', type: 'ABC', batch: 'COR01288C', net_qty: '50g', qrCode: url }
    }) 

    app.get('/generateLabel', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', renderdeet);  
    }
    );
    (async ()=> {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://localhost:5150/generateLabel');
        const dimensions = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return {
              width: document.body.clientWidth,
              height: document.body.clientHeight,
              deviceScaleFactor: 1
            };
          });
          await page.setViewport(dimensions)
        await page.evaluate(() => document.body.style.background = 'transparent');
        await page.screenshot({path: 'outputs/example'+i+'.png', omitBackground: true});
        await browser.close();
      })();
}

    app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${ port }`);
    });
```

Expected result would be getting 100 pictures in the outputs folder, each picture having a different QR code and labeling detail.

In actual result, there's either a memory error (using this method) or not getting screenshots at all due to problem with puppeteer functions

Answer (score 0):

You are creating & executing a function inside forloop, what you need to do is to create async function outside your for loop and then execute is using await inside for loop.

Secondly, you should open browser once before starting loop, then use page instance in for loop.

Make sure to close the browser after loop has ended.

The structure would be like:

```
{libraries}

{Start Browser and save it in a variable}

{loopstart}
    await myfunc(page)
{loopend}

{close browser}

{async myfun(page){}}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this before, and I just can't get it to execute. Can you please replace

  {Start Browser and save it in a variable}
 
  {loopstart}
    await myfunc(page)
  {loopend}

  {close browser}

  {async myfun(page){}}

with actual code?